# Formula to Concatenate All Combinations of Values Two Columns Without Macros in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns and am trying to concatenate all possible values of the two.

```
Col1  Col2
A     1
B     2
C
```

...etc...
So the result is:

```
A1
A2
B1
B2
C1
C2
```

...etc...

The other solutions posted on StackOverflow relate to Excel. I haven't been able to get the same formula's to work on Google Sheets

I have tried: `=TOCOL(A1:A3&TOROW(B1:B3))`

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You just have to wrap your formula in ArrayFormula.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(A1:A3&TOROW(B1:B3)))
```

Comment: You need to add ignore parameter `1` to ignore 3rd black cell of B column. `=ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(A1:A3&TOROW(B1:B3,1))).

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternate of ztiaa's solution.

```
=FLATTEN(INDEX(A1:A3&TRANSPOSE(B1:B2)))
```